# Can i use custom font for the image in java?

Tags: java

In above code i want to use custom font (which is commented on code), when i use commented font1 then iam not getting output properly.

```
BufferedImage source = ImageIO.read(input_file);
File backImg = new File("C:\\Users\\saradhi\\Desktop\\water-lily-3784022__340.jpg");
BufferedImage backImgB = ImageIO.read(backImg);
final BufferedImage textImage = new BufferedImage(
    backImgB.getWidth(),
    backImgB.getHeight(),
    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g = textImage.createGraphics();
FontRenderContext frc = g.getFontRenderContext();
/*
 * Font font1 = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new
 * File("C:\\Users\\saradhi\\Desktop\\Pacifico.ttf")); font1.deriveFont(9f);
 */
Font font = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 120);
GlyphVector gv = font.createGlyphVector(frc, name);
Rectangle2D box = gv.getVisualBounds();
int xOff = 25 + (int) - box.getX();
int yOff = 80 + (int) - box.getY();
Shape shape = gv.getOutline(xOff, yOff);
g.setClip(shape);
g.drawImage(backImgB, 0, 0, null);
g.setClip(null);

g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2 f));
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.setRenderingHint(
    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g.draw(shape);

g.dispose();

File file = new File("cat-text.png");
ImageIO.write(textImage, "png", new File("C:\\Users\\saradhi\\Desktop\\resultEX.jpeg"));
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
 As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
 See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: in above code i want to use custom font (which is commented on above code ), when i use commented font1 then iam not getting output properly

Comment: `font1.deriveFont(9f);` returns a new Font object.  It is not sufficient to just call the method;  you have to make use of the returned value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i get the custom font through this code

```java
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("C:\\Pacifico.ttf"))
    .deriveFont(48 f);
```